# Sending request from Dialogflow to Appscript with Authentication

Tags: google-apps-script, dialogflow-es

I'm having difficulties to send a fulfillment request from the Dialogflow to app script. Please notice I have no issue to send request from app script to Dialogflow. 
**My goal is to allow the Dialogflow to hit the app script web application and get the data from the integrated google sheet.** 
However, I could not figure out how to do it. My project network is restricted by the company. So it is impossible to publish the web apps for anyone to use. Then, I need to figure out how to send requests from the Dialogflow's fulfillment to the app script with the authorization like username, password or the OAuth token.
I spend a lot of time to find out the answers and still can not figure out how to make the request from Dialogflow to the app script. 
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!!!!

I already tried to send the request from Dialogflow to the app script bypassing the OAuth token. But the response is an HTML page for me to sign in the consent screen which I can not do it through the response. I am wondering is that possible to skip the consent screen. Also, what information do I need to put in the username or password part.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://glitch.com/~dialogflow-fulfillment-google-spreadsheet

Comment: Thanks for sharing the resource. That application does not hit the app script. The developer hosted his application in another server.